# how to duplicate and make tiny changes to existing angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

what I am trying to do here is to create a similar controller but not exactly the same, a few aspects of the controller need to be override. if it is the case in `java` then I probably just subclass and override the method I needed. but here in AngularJs not sure what is the best way to achieve this.

I really don't want to duplicate the code. refactoring the existing code is preferred but due to timeline issue have to delay that a bit.

so what is the correspondence of subclass and override in AngularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you really need controller inheritance (including $scope), I think your question is best answered here: [What's the recommended way to extend AngularJS controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/angular-extending-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service and inherit its behaviour in any controller just by injecting it.

```
app.service("reusableCode", function() {

    var reusableCode = {};

    reusableCode.commonMethod = function() {
        alert('Hello, World!');
    };

    return reusableCode;
});
```

Then in your controller that you want to extend from the above reusableCode service:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, reusableCode) {

    angular.extend($scope, reusableCode);

    // now you can access all the properties of reusableCode in this $scope
    $scope.commonMethod()

});
```

DEMO PLUNKER: http://plnkr.co/edit/EQtj6I0X08xprE8D0n5b?p=preview