# Creating a generic angularjs listController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-injector

Angular ui-router allows me to resolve different injections that I can use in my controllers.

I created a simple generic ListController, and in the ui-router I am injecting an object that contains the CRUD functions specific for that particular view, along with the template.

So, for example, let's say I have 2 services with the same "crud" syntax:

```
addPerson(person, callback){}
deletePerson(person, callback){}
editPerson(person, callback){}
....
addCar(car, callback){}
deleteCar(car, callback){}
editCar(car, callback){}
....
```

I created a mapping object to map these services' CRUD functions into my generic controller, which is injected through the ui.router.

GenericController:

```
controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'itemList', 'functions', function ($scope, itemList,   functions) {
    $scope.itemList = itemList;

    $scope.addItem = function(){
        functions.add($scope.item, callback);
    }
    .....
}
```

router:

```
        .state('app.people', {
            url: '/people',
            templateUrl: 'views/people.html',
            resolve: {
                    functions: ['People', function(People){
                        return {
                        add: People.createPerson,
                        update: People.updatePerson,
                        delete: People.deletePerson,
                        getItemList: People.getPeopleList
                    }
                    }],
                itemList: ['$q', 'People', function($q, People){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                    People.getPeopleList(function(resp, status){
                        deferred.resolve(resp);
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }],
                },
            controller: 'GenericController'
        })
```

So you can use it with the cars too by just injecting a different function mapping in its state definition.

Works like a charm.

But now I would like to be able to use my controller within a div, and not just in a full view. Now here's the problem:

If I use the ng-controller directive, the injector won't know what to provide as either 'itemList' or 'functions' (which is the mapping object), but if I instantiate it through the $controller object, then it won't have its own scope, and I get a

```
Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
```

because it won't be able to create its own child scope..
I guess I could create a new scope through $rootScope.$new() or something like that, but it feels too much like hacking, and since I'm new to angular, I think that this might be a bad approach for something like this..

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, I ended up writing a system of generic controllers, and tiny specialized controllers [that extend them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/angular-extending-controller).

For the example above, the generic controller is subclassed by both "PeopleController" and "CarController". At the beginning of the controller code, each one of them will do something like:

```
controller('PeopleController', ['$scope', 'peopleService', function ($scope, peopleService) {
angular.extend(this, $controller('listController', {$scope: $scope, functions:{

        add: peopleService.addPerson,
        remove: peopleService.removePerson,
        [...]

    }}));

    $scope.people = $scope.itemList;

}
```

So now I can instantiate the controllers on their own even in the ng-controller directive, and they will use the generic controller for all of the CRUD methods.