# AngularJS generic controller or controller inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

So upon building this application I have noticed that some of my controllers are almost identical. I like to keep things DRY so I was hoping to figure out a way to make a generic controller that other controllers can inherit from, but I got a little confused by some of the things I found.
Here is an example of 2 of my controllers so you can see the similarities:

```
.controller('CompaniesController', ['$state', '$filter', 'ArrayService', 'CompanyService', 'toastr', 'companies', 'roles', function ($state, $filter, arrayService, service, toastr, companies, roles) {

    // Assign this to a variable
    var self = this;

    // Get our companies
    self.companies = companies;

    // Our selected companies
    self.selected = [];
    self.send = {};
    self.delete = {};

    // Create our page sizes array
    self.pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];

    // For filtering and sorting the table
    self.pageSize = self.pageSizes[0];
    self.predicate = 'email';
    self.reverse = false
    self.filter = '';

    // Select method
    self.select = function (company) {

        // Modify our array
        arrayService.modify(self.selected, company);

        // If our array is only 1
        if (self.selected.length === 1) {

            // Get the current selected company
            var current = self.selected[0];

            // Set our variables
            self.canHaveCenters = (current.role === 'Company');
            self.requiresConfirmation = (!current.emailConfirmed);

            // Else
        } else {

            // Reset our variables
            self.canHaveCenters = false;
            self.requiresConfirmation = false;
        }
    };

    // Check to see if the row is selected
    self.isSelected = function (company) {

        // If our item is in our array, return true
        return (arrayService.indexOf(self.selected, company) > -1);
    };

    // Change to the edit company state
    self.edit = function (e, company) {

        // Change our state
        changeState(e, company, 'saveCompany.edit');
    };

    // Change to the company centers state
    self.centers = function (e, company) {

        // Change our state
        changeState(e, company, 'saveCompany.centers');
    };

    // Deletes a company
    self.delete = function (e, company) {

        // Perform the delete
        recursion(e, company, service.delete, self.delete, '{0} has been deleted.', '{0} companies have been deleted.', true);
    };

    // Private recursion method
    var recursion = function (e, company, serviceCall, resultObject, singleMessage, multipleMessage, removeAfterExecution) {

        // Stop propagation
        e.stopPropagation();

        // If we have an index
        if (typeof company !== 'undefined') {

            // If our delete succeeded
            serviceCall(company.id).then(function () {

                // If we are to remove
                if (removeAfterExecution) {

                    // Remove the company from our array
                    self.companies.data.splice(index);
                }

                // Display a message
                toastr.success($filter('stringFormat')(singleMessage, company.email));
            });

            // Otherwise we have no index
        } else {

            // Create our counter
            var i = 0;

            // Create a variable to hold our errors
            var errors = [];

            // For each selected company
            for (i; i < self.selected.length; i++) {

                // Get our index
                var index = self.selected[i];

                // Get the current company
                var company = self.companies.data[index];

                // If we have a result
                serviceCall(company.id).then(function () {

                    // If we are to remove
                    if (removeAfterExecution) {

                        // Remove the company from our array
                        self.companies.data.splice(index);
                    }

                    // If there is an error
                }, function (error) {

                    // Add to our errors array
                    errors.push(error);
                });
            }

            // If we have some errors
            if (errors.length > 0) {

                // Set our delete error
                self.error = errors.join();

                // Otherwise everything worked
            } else {

                // Display a message
                toastr.success($filter('stringFormat')(multipleMessage, i));
            }
        }
    };

    // Private state change method
    var changeState = function (e, company, state) {

        // Stop propagation
        e.stopPropagation();

        // If we have an index
        if (typeof company !== 'undefined') {

            // Change state
            $state.go(state, { companyId: company.id });

            // Otherwise we have no index
        } else {

            // If we have 1 selected item
            if (self.selected.length === 1) {

                // Get our index
                index = self.selected[0];

                // Get our company
                var company = self.companies.data[index];

                // Change state
                $state.go(state, { companyId: company.id });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

and

```
.controller('UserCentersController', ['$stateParams', 'ArrayService', 'CenterService', 'centers', 'userCenters', function ($stateParams, arrayService, service, centers, userCenters) {

    var self = this;

    // Get our user Id
    var userId = $stateParams.userId;

    // Assign our centers
    self.centers = centers;
    self.userCenters = userCenters;

    // Create our page sizes array
    self.pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];

    // For filtering and sorting the table
    self.pageSize = self.pageSizes[0];
    self.predicate = 'name';
    self.reverse = false;
    self.filter = '';
    self.selected = [];

    // Create a function to check if a center is in an array
    self.contains = function (center) {

        // Reference our data
        var data = self.userCenters.data;

        // If we have any data
        if (data) {

            // Check to see if our center is in the array
            return arrayService.indexOfByKey(data, 'id', center.id) > -1 ? true : false;
        }
    };

    // Adds the current center to the user
    self.add = function (e, center) {

        // Stop propagation
        modify(e, center, true);
    };

    // Removes the current center from the user
    self.remove = function (e, center) {

        // Stop propagation
        modify(e, center, false);
    };

    // Select method
    self.select = function (center) {

        // Modify our array
        arrayService.modify(self.selected, center);

        // Assign our variables
        self.canAdd = searchArray(self.userCenters.data, self.selected, false);
        self.canRemove = searchArray(self.userCenters.data, self.selected, true);
    };

    // Check to see if the row is selected
    self.isSelected = function (center) {

        // If our item is in our array, return true
        return (arrayService.indexOf(self.selected, center) > -1);
    };

    // Private method for checking if the selected items are all of the same state
    var searchArray = function (arrayToCheck, arrayToCompare, contains) {

        // Loop through the items to check
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayToCompare.length; i++) {

            // Get our current item
            var item = arrayToCompare[i];

            // See if our current id exis
            var found = arrayService.indexOfByKey(arrayToCheck, 'id', item.id) > -1;

            if (found != contains)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    // Private method for handling adding / removing or user centers
    var modify = function (e, center, adding) {

        // Stop propagation
        e.stopPropagation();

        // If we have an index
        if (typeof center !== 'undefined') {

            // Create a list
            var list = [];

            // Push our center into the list
            list.push(center);

            // Make our call
            service.modifyUserCenters(list, userId, adding).then(function () {}, function (error) {

                // Display our error
                self.error = error;
            });

            // Push to our user centers if it's not already there
            arrayService.modify(self.userCenters.data, center);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now there are obvious differences, but at the same time there are a lot of similarities. As I am not a JavaSript Guru, things like prototypical inheritance don't really mean anything to me.

I saw this question someone else asked:

[Creating a generic angularjs listController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061890/creating-a-generic-angularjs-listcontroller)

and it seems similar to what I want, but then I stumbled upon these 2 methods:

https://www.exratione.com/2013/10/two-approaches-to-angularjs-controller-inheritance/

and that is where I started getting confused.
For my case as you can see, I will probably have similar methods calls and will have some shared variables and functions. I have about 5 controllers that are similar in design and I can see that if I solve this, then I will have a few more for creating / editing controllers too.

Can someone give me, a laymen, a helping hand?