# angular: how to extend a controller without using $scope?

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope, extend

if you want to use a controller in recommended "controller as" fashion?

lets skip this part where extending a controller is a bad practice, i still believe there are cases where this is reasonable and useful.

been struggling with extending a controller in angularjs for a while, came up with the same as in here: [Angular: Extending controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/angular-extending-controller/19670187#19670187)
which i like the most of all choices. we still have a parent as an angularjs controller which makes sense in controller inheritance, i.e. it's not a service with $scope flying around, it's not a prototypical way which is most likely untestable, it's not a plain js function/object - it's angularjs controller we want to extend in angularjs controllers.

now the problem with this solution is one: what if we want to use it in recommended "controller as" way without $scope showing up? i couldn't find anything with that on web, tried to make my own:

```js
// @ngInject
function ParentCtrl(Service, CommonService) {
  var vm = this;

  //...

  // could be moved out to abstract extendable
  vm.extendTo = function(child) {
    // we need this reassignment to new vm reference,
    // to use overriden/child members in common/parent methods.
    vm = angular.extend(child, vm);
    return vm;
  };
}
angular.module('common').controller('ParentCtrl', ParentCtrl);

// @ngInject
function ChildCtrl($controller, SpecificService) {
  var vm = $controller('ParentCtrl', {Service: SpecificService}).extendTo(this);
}
angular.module('child').controller('ChildCtrl', ChildCtrl);
```

please, i need your opinions on possible pitfalls of this solution, suggestions of how to make this better, alternative ways. thank you.

Comment: just an other simpler approach https://gist.github.com/whisher/cf4ac38951f32bdcc59b