# Adding properties to Angular directive controller (e.g. FormController)

Tags: angularjs

How can I globally extend the native Angular [FormController](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController) with additional methods?

For example, I would like my forms to have an additional method `setNew()` (similar to already existing `$setPristine()`, etc). Right now I am doing this in each controller but I'd like it available throughout the app without declaring it all over the place.

Comment: What do you mean by native Angular FormController? Can you also give some explanation on the custom methods i.e what is their purpose?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/angular-extending-controller

Comment: @Nexus23 I saw that but that is about creating a new controller from an existing one - not sure how I would modify the native controllers

Comment: I guess it can be done by a decorator but the idea requires validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define additional behavior for directives by define other directives with the same name. Consequently, it seems you can do [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEqpeG?editors=101):

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('ngForm', formControllerDecorator)
  .directive('form', formControllerDecorator);

function formControllerDecorator () {
  return {
    require: 'form',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, formCtrl) {
      formCtrl.setNew = function () {
        // ...
      };
    }
  };
}
```

You need to declare two directives in this case, because `ngForm` is in fact an alias for `form`.

Comment: Pefect! I was building a directive to add to my form but this is much better.