# How to set a listener to every new scope created though ng-view directive or ng-controller directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like have a on listener something like below for all controllers which are instantiated. And, I don't want to include this expression in all of my controllers. I just wanted to set this listener on all new scopes created in angualr js application.

```
$scope.$on('somebroadcastedevent', function someEvent() {

});
```

How can I accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Override `ngController` directive.

```
module.directive('ngController', function () {
   return {
      link: function (scope) {
          // register the listener here. 
          scope.$on('somebroadcastedevent', function someEvent() {

          });
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: Hi Vinay
thanks for the answer. How about extending a base controller as suggested in this link?http://stackoverflow.com/q/16539999/1847031

Comment: This approach will not create any inheritance. To inject common properties in all the controllers this approach is very simple.

Comment: Just a note, this approach will not work when controller is instantiated using $controller.