# Inject service in all controllers

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I want to use https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification for notifications. I need them in all my controllers. Is it possible to inject 'Notification'(or '$log' or whatever) in all my controllers?

Comment: You just have to load `Notification` service in your controller as dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could by letting your controllers inherit from a common basecontroller. Something like this might work:

```
angular.module('extending', [])

.controller('baseController', function(someService) {
   this.someService = someService;
})

.controller('extendedController', function($scope, $controller) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('baseController', { $scope: $scope }));

   this.alert = this.someService.alert;
})

.service('someService', function() {
  this.alert = function() {
    window.alert('alert some service');
  };
});
```

HTML

```
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="extendedController as ex">
        <button ng-click="ex.alert()">Alert</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDdNgHVQ782nxRS7LR6w?p=preview). [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/angular-extending-controller) post on SO. AngularjS [extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) doc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is very helpfull

Comment: Wow, didn't know about the `extend` feature, +1