# AngularJS: inject dependency into every controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Suppose that I have a huge web application (that uses AngularJS) with a lot of controllers. Is there a way to **inject `$log` service in every controller**? To be more clear, I want to write something like this:

```
.config(function($log) {
    allMyControllers.inject($log);
})
```

instead of

```
.controller('Controller1', function($log) {...})
.controller('Controller2', function($log) {...})
.controller('Controller3', function($log) {...})
.controller('Controller4', function($log) {...})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the recommended way to extend AngularJS controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/whats-the-recommended-way-to-extend-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266653/inject-service-in-all-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Possible thing that you can do is, create a controller that has all needed dependencies and make it as base controller and other controllers can extend it using angular [extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) api.

some clear example code which I came accross :

```
.controller('baseController', function(someService) {
this.someService = someService;
})

.controller('extendedController', function($scope, $controller) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('baseController', { $scope: $scope }));

  this.alert = this.someService.alert;

})

.service('someService', function() {

  this.alert = function() {
    window.alert('alert some service');
  };
});
```

Working solution of above code can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDdNgHVQ782nxRS7LR6w).