# how to call function of page1(service1.html) controller( ctrl1 ) from another page2(service2.html) controller( ctrl2 ) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

> I try to call function of page1(service1.html) controller( ctrl1 )
>   from another page2(service2.html) controller( ctrl2 ) in angularjs.
>   The both page has parent controller (parentctrl). Anyone can give me
>   idea for fix this problem..

**Sample Code:**

```
app.controller("parentctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('emitdata', function(event, data) {
    $scope.$broadcast('broadcast-data', data);
  });
});

Page 1 : service1.html

app.controller("ctrl1", function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('broadcast-data', function(event, data) {
    $scope.received = data;
  })
});

Page 2 : service2.html
app.controller("ctrl2", function($scope) {
  $scope.emit = function() {
    $scope.$emit('emitdata', {'key': 'uu'});
  };
});
```

Comment: are you using ng-router or ui-router?

Comment: i have use ng-router

Comment: are you there bro..yes i have use ng-route

Comment: Well, I don't think ng-router allows you to have more then one route active at the same moment, so I guess your controllers are not both active and that could be why your ctrl1 $scope.$on is not working. I'd suggest you use ui-router if you need greater flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you're at route `service2` the scope of `service1` will be destroyed and vice versa.
So you can't pass it like this.

You could use a factory where you're storing the message or you could emit and store the received value at a variable at `$rootScope`.

With `$rootScope` or a factory you can add the received value to a `$scope` variable once you've entered the route.

I think a factory is better / cleaner but both will be OK.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zwg5tqm1/). (It uses the `$rootScope` method.)

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute'])
 .controller("parentctrl", function($rootScope, $scope) {
   $scope.$on('emitdata', function(event, data) {
      //$scope.$broadcast('broadcast-data', data);
      $rootScope.received = data;
    });
  })
  .controller("ctrl1", function($rootScope, $scope) {
   $scope.received = $rootScope.received || 'nothing received';
    /*scope.$on('broadcast-data', function(event, data) {
      $scope.received = data;
      console.log('received data', data)
    });*/
 })
  .controller("ctrl2", function($scope) {
    $scope.emit = function() {
      $scope.$emit('emitdata', {'key': 'uu'});
    };
 })
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('/service1', {
      templateUrl: 'service1.html',
      controller: 'ctrl1'
    })
    .when('/service2', {
      templateUrl: 'service2.html',
      controller: 'ctrl2'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/service1'});

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="parentctrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="service1.html">
   Service page 1
    {{received}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="service2.html">
   Service page 2
    <button ng-click="emit()">call service 1</button>
  </script>
  
  <div ng-view=""></div>
  <a href="#/service1">service 1 page</a>
  <a href="#/service2">service 2 page</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for gave idea..i got some knowledge from your words

Comment: can i inherit one page controller from another page controller?

Comment: Sure, you can read more about it in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/angular-extending-controller) and see it in action at this [fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zwg5tqm1/3/).