# How do I set up a parent controller with Angular UI-Grid defaults and inherit from it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angular-ui-grid

I have my default gridOptions in a parent controller.

EG:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
        rowHeight:50,
        headerHeight:50,
        onRegisterApi = function(gridApi,$scope){...}
}
```

The child controllers that implement UI-Grids all inherit the parent $scope and that seems to work fine for props with primitive types.

But, in the `onRegisterApi` function, I need to be able to access local variables and methods that are not in the parent scope.

I'm pretty sure I need to use a JS Inheritance pattern, but I'm having a hard time making it work. I've checked out: http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/
and https://www.exratione.com/2013/10/two-approaches-to-angularjs-controller-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [What's the recommended way to extend AngularJS controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/whats-the-recommended-way-to-extend-angularjs-controllers)

I put all my UI-Grid defaults in a base controller, which I then extend in the the controller that implements the grid. Seems to work fine without any $scope issues.