# how to set a master state for all urls on angular with ui-route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How I can use one `state` for all urls?
For example:

```
.state('home', {
    url:'/',
    template:'home.html',
    controller:'homeCtrl'
})
.state('user', {
    url:'/user',
    template:'user.html',
    controller:'userCtrl'
})
.state('master', {
    url:'*',
    controller:function() {
        console.log('hello!');
    }
})
```

I think in `*` for cath all urls, but when I try with this, nothing happend.

**My idea:**

When you open `/user` this trigger first `master` and after it, trigger `userCtrl`.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean ? Same url for all states or a common ancestor state ? If the latter just rename the state `user` to `home.user` and define every state as 'home.[something]` see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views

Comment: Don't do it this way. Create a separate 'master' controller and have the 'homeCtrl' & 'userCtrl' extend it. You can refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/whats-the-recommended-way-to-extend-angularjs-controllers

Comment: I confirm, both suggestions above are good, If you have only two or three states, it's better to use the first suggestion, else, you have to choose the second suggestion

Comment: I have around 30 controllers, maybe extend not is a good options. What's do you think @Hoyen?

Comment: @OlafErlandsen You have 30 state controllers? Because you only need to extend it for those, not every controller in your app.

Comment: My idea is append a "notification poll system" on `master` to show it on all states @Hoyen

Comment: @OlafErlandsen Yes, then create a 'masterStateCtrl' and in all the state controllers extend it 'angular.extend(this, $controller('masterStateCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));'