# angularjs extend controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

In detail.js

```
(function (module) {
    function DetailController($scope) {
         //long codes
    }
    module.controller('DetailController', DetailController);
})(angular.module('app.main'));
```

In main.js

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module('app.main', []);
    function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('app.main.detail', {
             url: 'detail',
             views: {
                 'detail@': {
                     templateUrl: 'app/main/detail.html',
                     controller: 'DetailController as vm'
                 }
             }
         })
    }
    module.config(config);
})();
```

How can I split detail.js controller into subcontroller?  because I have more than 1000 lines of code.  Thank you

Comment: You can probably move most of the logic to a service.

Comment: I moved lot of codes to service already.

Comment: what is that functionality you are doing? are you using multiple views?

Comment: no, I am not using multi views, there is only one detail view

Comment: what is that your want? 1000 loc in one view??

Comment: so, how can I split into multi view and multi controller?

Comment: You can create Mixin of multiple controllers. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/whats-the-recommended-way-to-extend-angularjs-controllers