# without touching core controller call the extended controller and accessing the core controller function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i am having a core controller

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    function FieldSettingsOverlay($scope, localizationService, formService, userService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.changeValidationType = changeValidationType;

        vm.validationTypes = [{
            "key": "number",
            "pattern": "^[0-9]*$"
        }, {           
            "key": "url",
            "pattern": "https?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
        }];

        function changeValidationType(selectedValidationType) {
            console.log("Parent")
        }
    }
    angular.module("umbraco").controller("UmbracoForms.Overlays.FieldSettingsOverlay", FieldSettingsOverlay);

})();
```

from this parent controller i have an array called vm.validationTypes , this is currently having only 2 objects but i have to add 3 or 4 objects.

so i have created a another controller by extend the core controller

// CustomValidation

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller('FromValidationCustomController', function ($scope, $controller) {
  'use strict';

console.log("inistiate")
  angular.extend(this, $controller('UmbracoForms.Overlays.FieldSettingsOverlay', {$scope: $scope}));
  $scope.changeValidationType=function(){

    console.log($scope.validationTypes)
  }
})
```

new extended controller using the same function called changeValidationType it is not even calling it where as only parent function calling

any idea what am i missing ? why this controller inside function not calling

Comment: `changeValidationType` is not defined in `$scope` in the `FieldSettingsOverlay` controller

Comment: @Satpal so how do i fix it ?

Comment: console.log(this.validationTypes), try this

Comment: hi but my new controller is not even calling i guess , so non eof the console is printing inside the FromValidationCustomController

Comment: how do i call my new controller called FromValidationCustomController ? this controller is not calling , due to that the events also not triggering

Comment: do you have router or html file? check whether the controller is included in router or in HTML as ng-controller = "FromValidationCustomController"

Comment: yes it is included

Comment: console.log("inistiate"); this line executed properly?

Comment: no , none of the console printing

Answer (score 0):

The posted code has issue.
Please check the updated minimum code section that works:

```js
(function(angular) {

 var module = angular.module('umbraco',[]);

 module.controller('UmbracoForms.Overlays.FieldSettingsOverlay', function($scope, $document) {
    this.validationTypes = [{
            "key": "number",
            "pattern": "^[0-9]*$"
        }, {           
            "key": "url",
            "pattern": "https?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
        }];
  this.changeValidationType = function() {
     console.log("Parent")
   return this.validationTypes;
  };
 });

})(angular);
var module = angular.module('example1',['umbraco']);
module.controller('FromValidationCustomController', function($scope, $controller) {
console.log("inistiate");
  angular.extend(this, $controller('UmbracoForms.Overlays.FieldSettingsOverlay', {$scope: $scope}));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="example1">
    <div ng-controller="FromValidationCustomController as C">
        <span><b>From Parent Controller:</b> {{C.changeValidationType()}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi but the FromValidationCustomController is not calling  , i have the view but the view no longer used i just add one empty div with ng-controller name on it ,

Comment: The view where ng-controller is defined, the html code need to be executed

Comment: i have to call the FromValidationCustomController on Page Load itself because the HTML is no longer available to call this FromValidationCustomController

Comment: For testing purpose, add the controller to a html view which is called. And check...

Comment: i have added already as i said before but it is not calling <div ng-controller="FromValidationCustomController" class="custom-form-validation" data-ng-init="init()"> 
</div>

Comment: Also you can check the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/whats-the-recommended-way-to-extend-angularjs-controllers

Comment: Please check the updated answer and use it as sample code.